# What alternative beside AspNet.Session

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-1.0, coreclr, asp.net5

I'm using Asp.net 5 with the framework `dnxcore50` and can't use the `dnx451` because gonna deploy to Linux. I can't use the `Microsoft.AspNet.Session` because it has some dependencies in the `.net 4.5.1` framework. I have a middleware and I need to set some data to the session so it'll be avaible latler. What choices do I have if I can't use the Session?

Comment: You may fork [Microsoft.AspNet.Session](https://github.com/aspnet/Session) and...manage to remove any dependency to _older_ 4.5.1 framework

Comment: It is an option. Thanx for the suggestion.

Comment: Well it ain't that simple. One of main dependency for the session is the cache and I would have to create it by myself. I haven't seen the source code but I guess it wouldn't by easy, otherwise it would be done already by the team.

Comment: Absolutely, it's not easy! Just doable